# Machine Learning/Artificial Intelligence - Classify column based on the value / pattern

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, weka

I have been trying some frameworks and algorithms, and I can't find one that do what I want - which is classify the column of the data based on the value.

I tried to use Bayes algorithm, but it isn't very precise because I can't expect that the data that is being searched for is in the training set - but I can expect that the pattern is in the training.

I don't have background in Machine Learning / AI, but I was looking for some working example before really going deeper in the implementation.

I built a smaller ARFF to exemplify. Also tried lots of Weka classifying algorithms but none of them gave me good results.

```
@relation recommend

@attribute class {name,email,taxid,phone}
@attribute text String

@data
name,'Erik Kolh'
name,'Eric Candid'
name,'Allan Pavinan'
name,'Jubaru Guttenberg'
name,'Barabara Bere'
name,'Chuck Azul'
email,'erik@gmail.com'
email,'steven@spielberg.com'
email,'dogs@cats.com'
taxid,'123611216'
taxid,'123545413'
taxid,'562321677'
taxid,'671312678'
taxid,'123123216'
phone,'438-597-7427'
phone,'478-711-7678'
phone,'321-651-5468'
```

My expectation is train a huge dataset like the above one and get recommendations based on the pattern, e.g.:

```
joao@bing.com -> email
Joao Vitor -> name
400-123-5519 -> phone
```

Can you please suggest any algorithms, examples or ideas to research?
I couldn't find a good fit, maybe it's just lack of vocabulary.

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with writing a few regexp's?

Comment: Well, for the given dataset, it's possible, but the scenario that I have has more complicated things then that. For example, I have a field called Name and another one called Company Name, and I would like to get suggestions  for "Stack Overflow Inc" as a company, and "Joao Vitor" as a name.

Comment: @JoaoVitor  Did you get the final solution?  I am faced with the exactly same problem. NEED HELP.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is called **named entity recognition** (NER). Weka is most likely not a real help here. The library Mallet (http://mallet.cs.umass.edu) might be a good fit. I would recommend a Conditional Random Field (CRF) based approach.

If you would like to stay with weka, you need to change your feature space. Then Naive bayes will be do ok on your data as presented
E.g. add a features for

- whether the word has only characters
- whether it is alphanumeric
- whether it is numeric data
- number of Numbers,
- whether it starts captilized
- ... (just be creative)

Comment: I definitely don't want to stay with Weka, mentioned it because I was trying to get good results with it, but no success. I'm taking a look in the recommended tools / algorithms, thank you!